# Black screenshots using c++ and cygwin sshd service

Tags: c++, winapi, cygwin, screenshot, sshd

I have a problem when trying to capture screenshots using c++ on windows xp.

The code is similar to this:

```
hDc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetDC(0), width, height);
HGDIOBJ obj = SelectObject(hDc, hBmp);
BitBlt(hDc, 0, 0, width, height, GetDC(0), 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

It runs fine on the machine normally, but when I login with ssh to the cygwin shell I just get a black screenshot running the same code. `BitBlt` returns 0 and `GetLastError` returns 6 which indicates an invalid handle. But none of the handles are 0. So how could I make this work, I am a bit lost as to what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

When you log into Cygwin over SSH, you don't have a screen (at least not one Windows knows how to see): you just have the sshd service - so you can't take a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Your login session probably doesn't have permission to use the desktop DC since it isn't part of the desktop.

**Edit:** If your intent is to get a screenshot of the Cygwin window only, you might be able to use the [`GetConsoleWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx) function to get the HWND of that window - assuming it exists in a sshd session.

Comment: Rather, `GetDC(0)` returns a DC for its own private desktop, where no applications are running, so it's black.

Comment: @Ben, that wouldn't explain the error returned from BitBlt. I'm sure the bitmap is black because that's how it was initialized.

Comment: Wouldn't one expect error 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`) and not error 6 (`ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`) in that case?  Possibly the DC for the service desktop doesn't have the `RC_BITBLT` capability.